# ER diagram - design issues

Tags: erd

There are 3 entities:

1. vehicle_model
2. vehicle
3. extra_options (such as open top, leather seats, etc..)

Vehicle model can have a subset of the extra options.
Vehicle can have a subset of it's model extras.

I've been trying hours to figure out how to represent this as er diagram, but without success. I Thought about ternary relationship ,and although I don't understand it completely I think this isn't the way.
I thought about creating another 2 entities, model_ext & vehicle_ext ,so that vehicle_ext would be connected to model_ext but this isn't a good design.

This is my first er diagram design. I'm really lost (read er-diagram chapter in "Silberschatz, Database System Concepts" three times already) so any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding a new table say 'vehicle_vehicle_model_extra_options_map'? (you can name this table to any thing short, but for better explanation i use __map as a standard way for defining the map tables.)

note those two null able foreign key columns in this table.
 Basically, vehicle has one to many relation to extra_options, and  vehicle_model has one to many relation to extra_options table, therefore the new table was added.
[image]

updated:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand how the constraint of vehicle's extras be a subset of it's model extras is satisfied in this diagram. Explanation would be awesome. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Understood. In that case, the 1-* from vehicle to vehicle_vehicle_model_extra_map should be deleted. That should take care of it.

Comment: Just to add to that, you said, 'Vehicle model can have a subset of the extra options.' 0-* from vehicle_model to vehicle_vehicle_model_extra_features_map takes care, and other thing you said 'Vehicle can have a subset of it's model extras.' its addressed via the 1-* relation between the vehicle and vehicle_model table.